# Как сделать запуск другого приложения?

Tags: android

Как сделать запуск других приложений. Когда пользователь нажимает на, допустим,  кнопку и открывается приложение, например "настройки"?

Comment: Вам стоит почитать о механизме намерений(Intents) в Android.

Сможете далеко не одни лишь "Настройки" открывать ;)

Comment: на хабре есть хорошая статейка http://habrahabr.ru/post/131041/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для запуска активности и получения от нее результата( 0 - идентификатор ответа ):

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Для обычного запуска нужной активности:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 0):

Окно настроек для автономного режима:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS));
```